# Parametrization of hypertorus $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: geometry, manifolds, parametrization

I'm looking for a parametrization of $T^3$ but have not been able to find one online. Can somebody offer one, point me to where I can find one, or provide instructions on setting one up? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you parametrize the circle?

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you mean by parametrization?

Comment: @Magma Something like the usual parametrization of $T^2$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrization_(geometry)

Comment: I know of several meanings of the word "parametrization" and "torus", some of which may apply here, so I need clarification from you. You could provide that usual parametrization of $T^2$ to show us what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to realize $T^3$ as a parametrized submanifold of $\mathbb R^6$:

$$f(u,v,w) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos u\\ \sin u\\ \cos v\\ \sin v\\ \cos w\\ \sin w\end{pmatrix}.$$

This generalizes easily to an embedding of $T^n$ in $\mathbb R^{2n}$.